# formatting timestamp to 1/100s / 1/10s of seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I could do the formatting of a timestamp to seconds as follows.

`to_timestamp('2017-02-20 08:22:44.166', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') --> 2017-02-20 08:22:44`

I need to format the above time stamp into 100s and 10s of seconds.

--> `2017-02-20 08:22:44.17`  (formatted to 1/100s of second)

--> `2017-02-20 08:22:44.2`  (formatted to 1/10 th of second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast a value to [timestamp with a specified precision:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

```
select '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(2), '2017-02-20 08:22:44.166'::timestamp(1)

       timestamp        |       timestamp       
------------------------+-----------------------
 2017-02-20 08:22:44.17 | 2017-02-20 08:22:44.2
(1 row)
```